# Can a non-compact manifold become compact by cutting it?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, dg.differential-geometry, gt.geometric-topology, riemannian-geometry, smooth-manifolds

I'm trying to understand a step in a proof, where one starts with a non-compact manifold $V$ containing a trapped (2-sided, closed) surface $\Sigma$ that's non-separating. In order to complete the proof, one needs to somehow double that manifold such that in the end one has a (still non-compact) manifold where the surface now separates it.
They do this by cutting the manifold $V$ along $\Sigma$, thus obtaining a (still connected) manifold $\tilde{V}$ with two separate boundaries diffeomorphic to $\Sigma$, and then gluing $\mathbb{Z}$ such copies of $\tilde{V}$ end-to-end along the boundaries. Then each ex-boundary ($\Sigma$) separates the new manifold.

My question is: why do I need $\mathbb{Z}$ such copies instead of just two? Can it happen that $\tilde{V}$ turns out to be compact, although $V$ wasn't?

Thanks guys.

Comment: If you used two copies the surface wouldn’t separate the resulting manifold.

Comment: I mean 2 copies glued together along just one of the boundaries instead of both?

Comment: Then you get a manifold with boundary (I assume you do not want it). Anyway, could you tell what do you need to prove with this trick (it might help).

Comment: Its the second part of the proof for a Variation of the Penrose singularity theorem, switching the condition that the Cauchy surface $V$ contains a trapped surface to $V$ contains a MOTS $\Sigma$ and additionally the generic condition holds on each future and past inextendible null geodesic normal to $\Sigma$. It's Theorem 3.2 from the paper "Topological censorship from the initial data point of view" from Eichmair, Galloway and Pollack.

Comment: What does MOTS mean? Anyway, if I understood it correctly, the answer to your second, more specific, question is “no” — if $V$ is non-compact then neither is $\tilde V$, however you construct it.

Comment: @HJRW A MOTS $\Sigma$ is a "marginally outer trapped surface", i.e. a trapped surface $\Sigma$ in a spacelike Cauchy hypersurface $V$ of a spacetime on which the null mean curvature w.r.t. the outward normal of $\Sigma$ in $V$ vanishes. (So it builds on a whole lot of other definitions of general relativity.)